# Contour plotting algorithm compliant with breaks and discontinues

Tags: algorithms

Good day,

Does anybody know where I could find a recursive contour plotting algorithm which is compliant with breaks and discontinues in the objective function? Recursive subdivision should be done only in those places where more sample points are needed to get a plot with smooth contours.

Comment: How is the objective function given? As an expression? As a black box? As data values on a grid?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest looking into [Jeff Tupper's successive refinement scheme](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/383259.383267), which does a pretty good job (the best that can be done with inexact arithmetic). This is the very method he used for his program GrafEq.

Comment: For those without ACM access, that paper is available on Tupper's website [here](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf).